# What format must an Application be in to Import it into IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm trying to import an Application into IIS7.5

I don't know what files/structure is expected. I assume it's a .zip file but should it just be:

- aspx and aspx.vb  page
- any .dll's it's dependent on
- other?

Comment: Is your project a Web Site or a Web Application Project?

Comment: From where you are trying to import application?

Comment: Have you tried [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939150/web-deployment-task-build-failed)?