# Cant publish asp.net with web deploy onto IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, webdeploy

I have quite a problem with web deployment from Visual Studio.
A few months ago it worked without any problems, but now I get this stupid error:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error Web deployment task failed. ((12.12.2018 21:29:45) An error                 
    occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)


    (12.12.2018 21:29:45) An error occurred when the request was processed on 
    the remote computer.

    Unable to perform the operation. Please contact your server administrator 
    to check authorization and delegation settings. S.E.P.P_WebApi      0
```

I just don't know what could have changed or what is wrong there.

I tried it with a completly new Asp.Net project and that didn't work either so I thought it must be the server where something was wrong. I just can't find what it could be because I haven't changed anything since the time it worked.

Please help

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I don't think it's the same question but the solution fixed it. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Mohsin Mehmood I could fix it.
The answer provided in this question:
[Web deployment task build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939150/web-deployment-task-build-failed)
could finally fix it. The problem was, that the users WDeployConfigWriter and WDeployAdmin, who are needed for Web-Deploy, have expiring passwords. Just changed that and it worked again.