# Visual studio cant publish asp.net core project to azure

Tags: azure, iis, deployment, web-deployment

I was following this article for deploying a ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I did everything there but it fails with a "An error occurred..." error. See the screenshot for details.

Since I am a begginer at both web development and deployment stuff please excuse my question here, I have tried to search it and couldnt apply a solution.

I have tried to change webdeploy user password in lusrmgr.msc in here: [Web deployment task build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939150/web-deployment-task-build-failed)
but since my os is windows home i couldnt be able to use it.

Also when clicking validate connection button in publish summary I got an error there too.

Screenshots:
[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: The publish failed because your build failed. It says that in the first screenshot "Build failed, check the output window for more details". So begin with looking in the output window in VS.

Comment: no, it is literally a basic template project from tutorial. no errors, no warnings.

Comment: Where are you publishing to?

Comment: to Azure linux server. I literally follow the tutorial desribed above.